# Как добавить некоторый текст в QTextEdit по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qpushbutton, qtextedit

Как можно вывести текст в `QTextEdit`?

*GUI* и *Main* прилагаю.
Пожалуйста, помогите.

**design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(561, 416)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 187, 192))
        self.textEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 50, 75, 23))
        self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 561, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "SOME TEXT will here ..."))
        self.button_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SOME TEXT"))
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from design import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку  

    def MyFunction(self):
       pass
         #a = "SOME TEXT";
         #    ?! appendPlainText(text)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from questions_992136_design import Ui_MainWindow                # design
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку  

    def MyFunction(self):
#       pass
         #a = "SOME TEXT";
         #    ?! appendPlainText(text)

        self.ui.textEdit.textCursor().insertHtml(                         # <=========
                       """ 
                       <b>insert</b> <br><i style='color: red;'>{}<i><br><br>
                       """.format(self.ui.button_1.text()))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from questions_992136_design import Ui_MainWindow                # design
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку  

    def MyFunction(self):
#       pass
         #a = "SOME TEXT";
         #    ?! appendPlainText(text)

        a = "SOME TEXT"; 
        self.ui.textEdit.append(a)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: В кнопке по умолчанию должен быть заложен текст: "НЕКОТОРЫЙ ТЕКСТ", а при нажатие, текст должен отправляться в textEdit.................Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @AlexandrS уточните что подсказать? Попробуйте так `self.ui.textEdit.textCursor().insertHtml(self.ui.button_1.text())`

Comment: @AlexandrS  я добавил еще один вариант

Comment: Вы гений..............БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО)))))))))))

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что в случае: self.ui.textEdit.textCursor().insertHtml(self.ui.button_1.text()) ____________ текст берётся с названия кнопки?

Comment: @AlexandrS  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop

Comment: ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ВОПРОС .... Пожалуйста, подскажите.... Новая кнопка добавляет текст на новую строку(будто у неё на конце имеется "\n"), каким образом можно добавлять новые текста (из новых кнопок) в ту же самую строку?

Comment: @@AlexandrS `QTextEdit::append(const QString &text)` 
Добавляет новый абзац с текстом в конец редактирования текста.

QTextEdit::insertPlainText(const QString &text)
Cлот для вставки текста в `текущей позиции курсора`.

Замените `self.ui.textEdit.append(a)` 
на       `self.ui.textEdit.insertPlainText(a)` это видимо то, что вам надо. 
Подробности читайте здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html